# Catching errors when querying in Django of fields that do not exist in the database or model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to catch errors of fields that do not exist either in the model or database. To do that I follow EAFP approach.

But it doesn't work, I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'bin_height_mm_desc' into field. Choices are:

```
def DeviceDetailView(request, device_id):   
    tbl_dict = {}
    try:
        tbl_dict  = Bin.objects.values('bin_height_mm_desc', 'received_at_ymd', 'received_at_hm')
    except (ValueError, TypeError, AttributeError) as e:
         tbl_dict = e   

   context = {
        'tbl_data' : tbl_dict,
    }

return render(request, 'applications/device.detail.html', context)
```

Comment: Fields for `values` are defined dynamically?

Comment: Yes, model name too. E.g. `Bin`

Comment: You may just want to check illigal field names with something like this `illigal_fields = [field for field in dynamic_fields if field not in your_model._meta.fields]` and then check if list is not empty `if illigal_fields: return {'fields_error': illigal_fields}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `django.core.exceptions.FieldError`.

```
    def DeviceDetailView(request,device_id):   
        tbl_dict = {}
        try:
            tbl_dict  = Bin.objects.values('bin_height_mm_desc','received_at_ymd','received_at_hm')
        except FieldError as e:
             tbl_dict = e   

        context = {
        'tbl_data' : tbl_dict,
       }
```

This class is a sub class of NameError so you could also catch NameError. To find out what kind of exception is raised you can try something like below.

```
try:
    tbl_dict  = Bin.objects.values('bin_height_mm_desc','received_at_ymd','received_at_hm')
except Exception as e:
    print(e.__name__)
    print(e.__class__)
```

Comment: This worked. Just need to import `from django.core.exceptions import FieldError`